# Is Sister Iris taken from Arthurian Legend?

Tags: cursed

One of the recurring characters in the series *Cursed* is Sister Iris.

In the series she ends up

> shooting Nimue with an arrow, possibly killing her.

Is this character taken from Arthurian legend, or was she created for the graphic novel/TV series?

Comment: No sign of her in The King Arthur Companion (by Phyllis Ann Karr), nor in Le Morte d'Arthur FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Never heard of the series *Cursed*. I don't recall coming across "Sister Iris" in any modern retelling of the Arthurian matter (say, up to Pyle) nor in any of the older romances  (Hartmann et al) nor in the Mabinogion.